# Deploy Meteor 1.3, React app on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, docker

I am trying to use
https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/tree/mupx
to deploy
https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/creating-an-app
on Amazon AWS. Everything goes well untill I get to
"mupx deploy".

```
    $ mupx init
    $ mupx setup
    (node:524) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. 
    If you are using the graceful-fs module, 
    please update it to a more recent version.


    Started TaskList: Setup (linux)
    [ec2-50-112-9-82.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com] - Installing Docker
    [ec2-50-112-9-82.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com] - Installing Docker: SUCCESS
    [ec2-50-112-9-82.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com] - Setting up Environment
    [ec2-50-112-9-82.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com] - Setting up Environment: SUCCESS
    [ec2-50-112-9-82.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com] - Copying MongoDB configuration
    [ec2-50-112-9-82.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com] - Copying MongoDB configuration: SUCCESS
    [ec2-50-112-9-82.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com] - Installing MongoDB
    [ec2-50-112-9-82.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com] - Installing MongoDB: SUCCESS



    $ mupx deploy


    Meteor app path    : /Users/peter/Desktop/meteor-com/simple-todos-react
    Using buildOptions : {"debug":true,"executable":"meteor"}
    buffer.js:106
          throw new Error(
          ^

    Error: If encoding is specified then the first argument must be a string
        at new Buffer (buffer.js:106:13)
        at Readable. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mupx/node_modules/archiver/lib/util/index.js:32:15)
        at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
        at Readable.emit (events.js:185:7)
        at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:926:12)
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Comment: Inside "mup.json" I changed "deployCheckWaitTime": 15 to 60. 

 $ mupx reconfig

 Started TaskList: Updating configurations (linux)
 [ec2.compute.amazonaws.com] - Sending environment variables
 [ec2.compute.amazonaws.com] - Sending environment variables: SUCCESS
 [ec2.compute.amazonaws.com] - Starting app
 [ec2.compute.amazonaws.com] x Starting app: FAILED
  
  ---STDERR---
  bash: /opt/simple-todos/config/start.sh: No such file or directory
  ---STDOUT---

Comment: Do I have to manually transfer my source files to AWS server or  mupx bundles it and copy everything to /opt dir on server?

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to Node.js version 6.*. Downgrading to < 6.0 should solve it. I'm using 5.1.1 for AWS deployments and it's working flawlessly. [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) is a great tool to manage node versions.

Comment: What is the suitable version of node and npm to use on local machine and server side. What version of node should I use in mup.json  "nodeVersion"?